# Joomla articles saving

Tags: joomla

I'd like to analyize the way Joomla saves articles to the database, does anyone knows where I can find the relative files and where I could get clarifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start looking at com_content. You should look here:

**/administrator/components/com_content**

If you use Joomla 1.7, almost all methods used by the com_content article model are used from the parent class (JModelAdmin, the class is defined in **/libraries/joomla/application/component/modeladmin.php**). For the article model, the save function performs a call to JModelAdmin::save, with some particularization if you're saving as copy or a featured article.
Besides, take in consideration the many plugins may interact with your article before and saving it (you can search in the plugins folders for methods like 'onContentBeforeSave' and 'onContentAfterSave').

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Joomla database structure [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Database_structure).

The Articles are saved in `Content` table. There you save the HTML... the images are located in the filesystem.